# Difference of using と and と一緒に as "taking action with someone"

Tags: particle-と

‎In Lesson 4 of Genki 1, it states that one of the meanings of と is "together with".
e.g. メアリーさんはスーさんと韓国に行きます。

However, the adverb of "together" is 一緒に and when と is added it has a nuance of "taking action together with someone".
e.g. 私は彼と一緒に学校にいきます。

What is the difference between using just "と" and using "と一緒に"?

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: you might start by considering the english equivalents:  what’s the difference between saying “she went with mary” and “she went together with mary”?

Comment: So the 2nd one is just emphasizing that you're doing the action together?

Answer (score 6):

と is like "with", a particle to mark other parallel agent(s) involved in an action. That means:

> メアリーさんはスーさんと韓国に行きます。
> メアリーさんはスーさんと一緒に韓国に行きます。

They basically mean the same thing, but:

> アメリカはソ連と戦います。 *USA fights with USSR.*
> アメリカはソ連と一緒に戦います。 *USA fights together with USSR.*

～と戦う is just like "fight with", where you don't know what comes after is a friend or foe. Using と一緒に makes sure that it is in your party. (Note: Japanese has no equivalent of "fight against", so ～と戦う tends to mean the opponent.)

The same applies to ～と連絡を取る "make contact with" or ～と向かい合う "face with".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the explanation from Genki - と一緒に has an emphasis that you are doing an action together with someone. Having said that, I would say they are quite interchangeable.